# Django object existence

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wanted to check that object exists in the db, and if it does not exist, to add it to the database.
I tried:

```
if not MyModel.objects().get(surname='foo'): 
     management.call_command('loaddata', 'Bootstrap_data', verbosity=0)#adds this object from fixtures
```

But I get a query error from db(sqlite3). How can this way of object validation be resolved?

The error is:

```
DoesNotExist at /
MyModel matching query does not exist.
```

It is because there is no object with this surname in the db.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically you'd use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

```
model_instance = MyModel.objects.get_or_create(surname='foo')
```

You shouldn't really be using `management.call_command` for something like this.

That said, if I've misunderstood and you have a good reason, try this:

```
try:
    MyModel.objects.get(surname='foo')
except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
      management.call_command(....)
```

OR

```
if not MyModel.objects.filter(surname='foo').exists():
      management.call_command(....)
```

Comment: Not useful in his case; he wants to load from fixtures, not with code.

Comment: Just updated my answer in case you were doing this for some fixture-related reason :)

Comment: Filter worked) thanks. I don't like to process application logic with exceptions instead of conditions, filter is better.

Answer (score 1):

```
if not MyModel.objects.filter(surname='foo').exists()
```

[RTFriendlyM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exists)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that the `MyModel.objects.get` will raise `DoesNotExist`, try using `exists` instead:

```
if not MyModel.objects.filter(surname='foo').exists():
    management.call_command('loaddata', 'Bootstrap_data', verbosity=0)
```